# Prove that there is a $m$ that $f(m)=m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

think that $n$ is a natural number and $A$ is the set of the divisors of $n$. Let $f:A \longrightarrow A$ be a function such that if $a \mid b$ then $f(a) \mid f(b)$. Prove that there is a $m$ that $f(m)=m$.

We have learned this kind of questions in the previous class then I cannot do anything.And because of that please give full answers.Thanks.

Comment: Please don't give close vote until it gets an answer I need it.I have appologized for my low works.We learned them the previous class because I have ni ideas to solve.

Comment: The close vote is probably because you haven't shared any of your own work. Have you checked any simple cases, for instance?

Comment: I don't can understand the question how can I share my thoughts?

Comment: For instance, if $n=5$, what is $A$? What are the possible $f$'s?

Comment: If you don't understand the question.  Lets walk through an example  Suppose $n=6.$ Then  $A = \{1,2,3,6\}.$  If $f(1)=2, f(2) = 2$ or $6, f(3) = 2$ or $6, f(6)= 2$ or $6.$  If $f(6) = 2$ then $f(2) = 2.$  Generalizing $f(1) \ne 1, f(n)\ne n$ severely limits how the other elements can map.

Comment: If you do not understand the question, then a proof will not enlighten you. Do some examples, like the one given, for small $n$ and get the idea of the mapping. Then, and only, can a proof be helpful

Comment: Uh.... $f=2x$ and $n=3^k$ seems to be a counterexample.

Comment: @abnry That doesn't fit $f:A\to A$ though.

Comment: Consider the sequence $\bigl(f^{k}(1)\bigr)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, I don't see what you mean, can someone elaborate please?

Comment: @Jam Let $a_k = f^k(1)$. Clearly $a_0 \mid a_1$, hence inductively $a_0 \mid a_1 \mid a_2 \mid \dotsc$. So this is a nondecreasing sequence of positive integers. And it's bounded (by $n$).

Comment: @DanielFischer Nice one. Thanks, sir.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Sorry for my silly question but why it is bounded (by $n$).

Comment: What is the largest divisor of $n$?

Comment: @DanielFischer but it is not a nondecresing sequence of positive integers it is a sequence of integers.

Comment: @DanielFischer think that $f(1)=-1$ and $f(-1)=1$ then we will never get to a $m$ that $f(m)=m$

Comment: Since $n$ is specified as a natural number, I assumed that $A$ should be a subset of $\mathbb{N}$. If $A = \{ k \in \mathbb{Z} : k \mid n\}$, then for a nonzero $n$ the map $k \mapsto -k$ has no fixed point. Since the context strongly suggests $A\subset \mathbb{N}$, and the assertion doesn't hold if we include the positive and the negative divisors, it's a pretty safe bet that the set of natural numbers dividing $n$ is intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursive proof:

$n=1$ $f(1)=1$. done.

Suppose $f(n)=n$ done.

Suppose $f(n)=m<n$, for every $a|n, f(a)|m, f(a)$ is an element of $A_m$ 
 the set of divisors of $m$. Let $g$ be the restriction of $g$ to $A_m$, if $a,b\in A_m, a|b, g(a)=f(a)$ divides $f(b)=g(b)$. Recursively, we deduce that there exists $p\in A_m$ such that $g(p)=f(p)=p$.

Answer (score 1):

Induction. The base step, for $n=1$, is trivial.

We fix $n$ and assume that the statement is true for numbers lesser than $n$.

If $f(1)=1$ we are done. Otherwise, assume that $d=f(1)>1$. Then $d$ must be a divisor of $n$, because $d\mid f(1)\in A$. The number $d$ also divides $f(a)$ for every $a\in A$.

Let $B$ be the set of the divisors of $n/d$. Define 
$$f_d(b)=\frac1df(db)$$
for $b\in B$. The function $f_d:A\to A$ is well defined and meets the property. Since $n/d<n$, we can apply the induction hypothesis to say that there is some $m_d$ such that $f_d(m_d)=m_d$, that is, 
$$m_d=\frac1df(dm_d),$$
QED